# pip doesn't fetch any url

Tags: python, pip

I've just installed python 3.4 (from source) and I want to use pip to download packages. But every time I run it using e.g.:

```
pip install -v django
```

I get following error (Same output as in /root/.pip/pip.log:

```
/var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/bin/pip run on Thu Apr  3 18:16:44 2014
Downloading/unpacking django
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/ when looking for download links for django
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for django:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/ when looking for download links for django
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/build...
No distributions at all found for django
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/var/www/sova_move/newvenv/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for django
```

my connection is fine (I can normally upgrade my system, ping google...) and https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ definetly exist (I can see it right now). Furthermore - I can use pip list, pip search and when I manually download package using wget and then use

```
python setup.py install
```

it works OK and it even can download dependencies. I'm not using proxy. This is being done on raspbery pi with archlinux. My connection is static. Python is working OK and pip is also installed (by default in 3.4).

Thanks

Comment: What does `pip install django` do?

Comment: Downloading/unpacking django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fresh reinstall of my virtualenv using local version of python without using symbolic links and it works now. Thank you